# Should I flag a question in which the OP includes their phone number?

Tags: discussion, questions, flags

For example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684695/error-regarding-kreplacements-kreplacements-h) the OP includes his/her phone number.  Personally I don't think that's a great idea, but

1. Does it violate any StackExchange policies?
2. Should I take any action (flag, comment and recommend against this behavior, etc.)?

*Edit:* Based on the number of responses specific to taglines I want to clarify that I got the sense from the post that the OP was hoping someone would call him to discuss possible solutions.  I agree with the tagline comments about removing it, but am curious about whether we'd remove the number if the OP explicitly solicited phone contact (e.g., `Please call me at xxx-xxx-xxxx`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This would count as a "signature", and definitely should be edited out as a result (as someone has already done). But also, you are correct in thinking contact information should not be in questions/answers.

One suggestion for these users is that they can put anything like that in their profile, if they like.

Usually a user will edit out such things if they are found, and it's a valid suggested edit if you can't do those yourself. If someone is rolling those edits back, that would be a time to flag for a moderator.

Comment: As said, please edit the number. You will do a favor to the community by removing noise and a favor to the user by removing his contact information from a page that will get crawled for farming such info.

Comment: PS: Unicorn, that hat is hiding your head... now you seem just a normal pony. Are you on a secret mission by chance?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Ack!!!